# Como criar um instalador (setup) para tabelas e conexão com o banco?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de agradecer desde já colaboração.
Sei que é possível, porem ainda não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Eu tenho um script porem ele será utilizado para venda, porem gostaria que no meio ao script tivesse uma forma de ele perguntar ao cliente quais os dados de conexão como, (localhoat,root,pass,BD) e apos conexão efetuada com sucesso inserir as tabelas no banco de dados.

Parecido com o início do WordPress.

[image: SS]

Comment: Perguntar ao usuário? Eu não entendi.

Comment: Sim, digamos que você inseriu a pasta na localhost. Ao insvez de inserir o arquivo SQL no phpMyAdmin, automaticamente o script antes de entrar no sistema ele pede ao cliente os dados de conexão ao servidor e apos conexão ele inserir as tabelas.

Comment: Eu acho que já vi essa pergunta aqui. Mas não tenho certeza, me diz o que você quer é algo semelhante a isto http://i.stack.imgur.com/QnUZW.png ?

Comment: Eu até acho uma dúvida válida, mas entendo que é ampla demais para uma pergunta só. Basicamente o que o script vai fazer é ver se já existe um arquivo de configuração, se não existe, pergunta os dados e salva. Mas é bom você dizer quais partes sabe fazer e quais não sabe. Sabe verificar se um arquivo existe? Sabe gerar um arquivo texto e salvar? Sabe fazer um formulário básico e pegar os dados? Sabe usar os dados e testar a conexão? E assim por diante.

Comment: Não, Guilherme... Pelo jeito você não entendeu.. A isso https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCTdSuAhMNCGSG_mTmr2faRgec9wrDb0i3fIFLkYKCEXJG78HQhCjNjPQXbQ

Comment: Não é que eu não entendi, é que estava dificil mesmo de entender. O que você quer é um setup de instalação ou um ambiente de configuração? Porque se for isso, não dá pra entender porque um usuário (acho que é um sistema de vendas) teria que ter acesso a dados do banco de dados. Se for um ecommerce, ele tem que ter um login e senha, mas a parte, o sistema em si não pode requisitar dados do banco real, o melhor na verdade seria você criar um banco (ou mais) e cada usuário com sua credencial seria autologado no seu banco (que pode ser compartilhado) especifico.

Comment: Realmente agora mudou totalmente o sentido, tive até que deletar a resposta, vou tentar formular uma resposta assim que tiver um tempo.

Answer (score 2):

## Modificações dentro do sistema principal

No seu script (o sistema que será vendido), ele deverá verificar se existe o arquivo `config.inc.php`, que no nosso caso, vai (ou deveria estar) na pasta `system`.

```
if (!file_exists('system/config.inc.php')) {
    echo "Clique <a href='./install/' title='Iniciar instalacao'>aqui</a> para iniciar a instalacao do sistema.";
    exit;
}
```

Explicando o código acima: ele irá verificar se o arquivo `config.inc.php` existe dentro da pasta `system`. Perceba que colocamos um operador de negação `!` antes da função, ou seja, se não existir ele retorna `true` e executa o código dentro da condição, que apenas exibe uma mensagem e um link pra pasta `install/` (que irá conter o sistema de instalação) e interrompe a execução do script usando exit.

Se o arquivo `config.inc.php` já existir, é interessante também colocar uma nova condição (abaixo da anterior) para verificar a pasta `install` existe, se sim, nós vamos obrigar o usuário a deletá-la para poder usar o sistema, já que manter essa pasta seria um risco de segurança.

```
if (file_exists('install/')) {
    echo "Por favor, delete a pasta install.";
    exit;
}
```

Pronto, são somente essas as alterações dentro do sistema que você irá vender. Agora teremos que criar um novo sistema para fazer a instalação.

É interessante que ele não dependa de nenhum arquivo do sistema principal, ou seja, todo arquivo css, imagens, arquivos de conexão com banco, funções, enfim... tudo deve existir dentro da pasta `install` para ser utilizado apenas pelo instalador.

## Criando o instalador

Crie um arquivo `index.php` dentro da pasta `install`. Esse arquivo será responsável por chamar as páginas de acordo com o step (progresso) que será passado via `$_GET`. Veja o modelo abaixo e modifique conforme suas necessidades.

```
<?php

    $step = (isset($_GET['step'])) ? (int) $_GET['step'] : null;

    //Quantidade de etapas que seu instalador irá ter.
    $qntEtapas = 3;

    if (empty($step) || $step > $qntEtapas) {
        header('Location: ./?step=1');
    }

    //Crie uma pasta chamada step e dentro dela, coloque as páginas seguindo o modelo: pagina-1.php pagina-2.php pagina-3.php, conforme a quantidade de etapas.
    require_once 'step/pagina-' . $step . '.php';
```

Agora você tem que construir o layout das páginas de cada etapa, o que foge um pouco do assunto, por isso não irei dizer como fazer. Mas, vou dar uma dica: as páginas de cada etapa, normalmente, só irão ter o o formulário de diferente, então seria interessante você criar 2 arquivos `.php` chamados `header.php` e `footer.php`, e inclui-los, deixando as páginas das etapas mais limpas e facilitando a manutenção.

Abaixo, um exemplo de uma página de etapa (com os mesmos campos da imagem que você postou do WordPress).

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $database = (isset($_POST['database'])) ? trim($_POST['database']) : null;
    $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;
    $hostname = (isset($_POST['hostname'])) ? trim($_POST['hostname']) : null;
    $dbprefix = (isset($_POST['dbprefix'])) ? trim($_POST['dbprefix']) : null;

    if (!empty($database) || !empty($username) || !empty($hostname)) {

        //Nesse caso em especifico, precisamos fazer uma conexão com o banco
        //usando os dados informados pelo usuário, para ter certeza de que estão
        //corretos.

        function dbTest($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
            try {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
                return $pdo;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (dbTest($hostname, $username, $password, $database)) {

            //Se a conexão der certo, cria (caso não exista) o arquivo config.inc.php
            //dentro da pasta system e escreve os dados nele.
            file_put_contents('../system/config.inc.php',
                '<?php'
              . '    $hostname = ' . "'{$hostname}'; \n"
              . '    $username = ' . "'{$username}'; \n"
              . '    $password = ' . "'{$password}'; \n"
              . '    $database = ' . "'{$database}'; \n"
              . '    $dbprefix = ' . "'{$dbprefix}'; \n"
            );

            //Redireciona para próxima etapa, se for o caso.
            header('Location: ./?step=2');
        } else {
            echo 'Desculpe, mas não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados informado.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Por favor, preencha os campos corretamente...';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Instalando sistema | Etapa 1 de 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="database">Nome do banco</label>
            <input type="text" id="database" name="database"><br>
            <label for="username">Usuário</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
            <label for="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
            <label for="hostname">Servidor MySQL</label>
            <input type="text" id="hostname" name="hostname" value="localhost"><br>
            <label for="dbprefix">Prefixo da tabela</label>
            <input type="text" id="dbprefix" name="dbprefix">
            <hr>
            <button type="submit">Ir para próxima etapa</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perceba que o grande X da questão é a função `file_put_contents`, é ela quem irá gravar os dados passados no arquivo especificado.

Para inserir tabelas no banco de dados informado pelo usuário, basta você executar uma query normalmente, só que colocando o código SQL para criação da mesma.

O código SQL você deve fazer manualmente, ou criar as tabelas via phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench ou qualquer outro programa que te ajude com isso, depois copiar o SQL gerado e colocar no seu script pra rodar como uma query normal.

É a mesma coisa que dar um `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = 1;` só muda o comando SQL.

É basicamente isso. Agora é dar uma estudada no que foi dito aqui, e melhorar o código pra se adequar bem as suas necessidades.

## Leituras recomendadas

[Função file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)
[Operador ternário no PHP](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/operador-ternario)
[Função file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php)